# Question about fiber of projection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Mumford’s Red book, a projection is defined as follows:

Given linear forms $l_0=0,l_1=0,…,l_r=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$. Let $U_i=Spec(k[\frac{X_0}{l_i}, \frac{X_1}{l_i},…, \frac{X_n}{l_i}])$,$V_i=Spec(k[\frac{Y_0}{Y_i}, \frac{Y_1}{Y_i},…, \frac{Y_r}{Y_i}])$. We can define a projection $p:\mathbb{P}^{n+1}-L\to \mathbb{P}^r$ by requiring that $p(U_i)\subset V_i$, where $L$ is a linear space defined by the linear forms above.

Then it’s said that for a point $x\in \mathbb{P}^{n+1}-L$, $p^{-1}(p(x))$ is the smallest linear space that contain $L$ and $x$. I don’t know why this follows? Surely $L$ is map to zero, but why the fiber is a linear space containing $L$ and $x$?

Take an example, put $n=r=1$, $l_0:X_0=0,l_1:X_1=0$, then $L$ is a line, and a fiber would be a plane in this case, which is quite weird to me. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: How can $p^{-1}(p(x))$ contain $L$ when $L$ is not contained in the domain of $p$?

Comment: May the map is extended to the whole $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$?